# Injector python + http proxy basic proxy authentication

Tags: python-2.7, http-proxy

Could someone help me join these two pieces of code to be able to use HTTP proxy authentication in the `injector.py`?

**injector.py** - Not perfect but it works and it's the one I'm using

```
######################################
#########__Injector Python__##########
######################################

BIND_ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
BIND_PORT = 8989
PROXT_ADDR = ''
PROXY_PORT = 
PAYLOAD = ''



import socket
import thread
import string
import select

TAM_BUFFER = 65535
MAX_CLIENT_REQUEST_LENGTH = 8192 * 8

#Monta uma payload
def getReplacedPayload(payload, netData, hostPort, protocol):
    str = payload.replace('[netData]', netData)
    str = str.replace('[host_port]', (hostPort[0] + ':' + hostPort[1]))
    str = str.replace('[host]', hostPort[0])
    str = str.replace('[port]', hostPort[1])
    str = str.replace('[protocol]', protocol)
    str = str.replace('[crlf]', '\r\n')
    return str

#Separa o protocol HTTP de uma requisicao
def getRequestProtocol(request):
    inicio = request.find(' ', request.find(':')) + 1
    str = request[inicio:]
    fim = str.find('\r\n')

    return str[:fim]

#Separa o host e porta de uma requisicao
def getRequestHostPort(request):
    inicio = request.find(' ') + 1
    str = request[inicio:]
    fim = str.find(' ')

    hostPort = str[:fim]

    return hostPort.split(':')

#Separa a request line de uma requisicao
def getRequestNetData(request):
    return request[:request.find('\r\n')]

#Le uma request/response HTTP
def receiveHttpMsg(socket):
    len = 1

    data = socket.recv(1)
    while data.find('\r\n\r\n'.encode()) == -1:
        if not data: break
        data = data + socket.recv(1)
        len += 1
        if len > MAX_CLIENT_REQUEST_LENGTH: break

    return data

#Implementa o metodo CONNECT
def doConnect(clientSocket, serverSocket, tamBuffer):
    sockets = [clientSocket, serverSocket]
    timeout = 0
    print '<-> CONNECT started'

    while 1:
        timeout += 1
        ins, _, exs = select.select(sockets, [], sockets, 3)
        if exs: break

        if ins:
            for socket in ins:
                try:
                    data = socket.recv(tamBuffer)
                    if not data: break;

                    if socket is serverSocket:
                        clientSocket.sendall(data)
                    else:
                        serverSocket.sendall(data)

                    timeout = 0
                except:
                    break

        if timeout == 60: break

#Atente um cliente
def acceptThread(clientSocket, clientAddr):
    print '<-> Client connected: ', clientAddr

    #Le a requisicao cliente
    request = receiveHttpMsg(clientSocket)

    #Valida o metodo. Somente CONNECT e aceito
    if not request.startswith('CONNECT'):
        print '<!> Client requisitou metodo != CONNECT!'
        clientSocket.sendall('HTTP/1.1 405 Only_CONNECT_Method!\r\n\r\n')
        clientSocket.close()
        thread.exit()

    #Separa dados da request enviada
    netData = getRequestNetData(request)
    protocol = getRequestProtocol(request)
    hostPort = getRequestHostPort(netData)

    #Gera a requisicao final a partir da payload, com base nos dados da request enviada
    finalRequest = getReplacedPayload(PAYLOAD, netData, hostPort, protocol)

    #Envia a requisicao ao servidor proxy
    proxySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    proxySocket.connect((PROXT_ADDR, PROXY_PORT))
    proxySocket.sendall(finalRequest)

    #Recebe a resposta do servidor proxy
    proxyResponse = receiveHttpMsg(proxySocket)

    print '<-> Status line: ' + getRequestNetData(proxyResponse)

    #Envia a resposta do proxy ao cliente
    clientSocket.sendall(proxyResponse)

    #Se a resposta do proxy contem codigo 200, executa metodo CONNECT
    if proxyResponse.find('200 ') != -1:
        doConnect(clientSocket, proxySocket, TAM_BUFFER)

    #Fecha a conexao com o cliente
    print '<-> Client ended    : ', clientAddr
    proxySocket.close()
    clientSocket.close()
    thread.exit()


#############################__INICIO__########################################

print '\n'
print '==>Injector.py'
print '-->Listening   : ' + BIND_ADDR + ':' + str(BIND_PORT)
print '-->Remote proxy: ' + PROXT_ADDR + ':' + str(PROXY_PORT)
print '-->Payload     : ' + PAYLOAD
print '\n'

#Configura a escuta numa porta local
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((BIND_ADDR, BIND_PORT))
server.listen(1)

print '<-> Server listening... '

#Recebe o cliente e despacha uma thread para atende-lo
while True:
    clientSocket, clientAddr = server.accept()
    thread.start_new_thread(acceptThread, tuple([clientSocket, clientAddr]))

server.close()
```

Basic Proxy Authentication - Example

This is an example I found about http proxy authentication in python

```
import httplib,base64,socket

user='proxy_login';passwd='proxy_pass'
host='login.yahoo.com';port=443
phost='proxy_host';pport=80

#setup basic authentication
user_pass=base64.encodestring(user+':'+passwd)
proxy_authorization='Proxy-authorization: Basic '+user_pass+'\r\n'
proxy_connect='CONNECT %s:%s HTTP/1.0\r\n'%(host,port)
user_agent='User-Agent: python\r\n'
proxy_pieces=proxy_connect+proxy_authorization+user_agent+'\r\n'

#now connect, very simple recv and error checking
proxy=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
proxy.connect((phost,pport))
proxy.sendall(proxy_pieces)
response=proxy.recv(8192) 
status=response.split()[1]
if status!=str(200):  raise 'Error status=',str(status)

#trivial setup for ssl socket
ssl = socket.ssl(proxy, None, None)
sock = httplib.FakeSocket(proxy, ssl)

#initalize httplib and replace with your socket
h=httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost')
h.sock=sock
h.request('GET','/')
r=h.getresponse()
print r.read()
```

Comment: Did you make any effort to solve this on your own and run into problems, or are you asking for us to do your work for you?